# Core J2EE patterns and practices still relevant to read?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have been using Java for a while (about 12-18 months), and wanted to know if the Core J2EE book was still relevant, and if i should read it?

Comment: You are talking about this book, right? http://www.amazon.co.uk/Core-J2EE-Patterns-Microsystems-Press/dp/0130648841

Comment: yes but the second edition http://www.amazon.co.uk/Core-J2EE-Patterns-Practices-Strategies/dp/0131422464/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1354096520&sr=1-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the book that Fildor links to, then that was last updated in 2003, somewhere between Java EE 1.3 and 1.4. That was a long time ago; current version of Java EE differ *enormously* from that. There has been the revolution that was dependency injection frameworks, and the landscape of web frameworks and REST libraries has matured to the point where you very rarely write your own controller servlets.

If you are interested in working with EE 5 or EE 6, then i'm afraid that book is hopelessly out of date. If, on the other hand, you are working on a legacy project that is using EE 1.4, then it might actually be useful!

The book's website has a handy diagram of the patterns it covers (with broken links):

http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/

The list has a very old-fashioned feel. Data Transfer Object, Service Locator, mmm ...

Comment: One can argue that the "old-fashionedness" of it is that it is all based on a need to follow what other people tell you to do in stead of using your brain and coming up with something that is small, simple and self-contained and that works given a problem description, budget and expected usage. Patterns are too generic, problems you need to solve hardly ever are generic.

Answer (score 8):

I think the books written by Adam Bien are better: Real World Java EE Patterns: Rethinking Best Practices. http://press.adam-bien.com/

Comment: Those books look really good - i think i might buy myself one as a christmas present. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the list of previous response, I think for Java EE 6, Antonio Goncalves's book on Java EE 6 and GlassFish may be a nice reading.

See here for example: http://www.amazon.fr/Beginning-Java-EE-GlassFish-Second/dp/143022889X/
For information, Antonio Goncalves is a member of the expert group which is writing the Java EE specifications.